# Are the new limits of this triple integral fine $\iiint_E\, (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)\, dx\, dy\, dz$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Are the new limits of this triple integral fine?
>
> $\iiint_E\, (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)\, dx\, dy\, dz$ where $E:
>  \{(x,y,z) |  x,y,z\geq0, x+y+z \leq a\}$, $a$ is positive constant

Under the transformation $$x+y+z=u$$

$$x+y=uv$$

$$x=uvw$$

$$\Rightarrow x=uvw, \, y= uv(1-w), \, z=u(1-v)$$

$$ \{(x,y,z) |  x,y,z\geq0, x+y+z \leq a\} \Leftrightarrow \{(u,v,w) |  0\leq u\leq a, 0\leq v \leq 1, 0\leq w \leq 1\}$$

$$\iiint_E\, (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)\, dx\, dy\, dz \Leftrightarrow 
\int_{w=0}^{1}\,\int_{v=0}^{v=1}\int_{u=0}^{a} \, F(u,v,w)\,du\,dv\,dw$$

Is this correct?

Comment: bounds for $u,v$ seems right. how did u get the bounds for $w$?

Comment: Where is thd jacobian?

Comment: @dezdichado from $0 \leq uv(1-w) \leq1 $

Comment: @StubbornAtom Jacobian is $u^2v$ but doesn't matter as the question only requires the limit of new integral